# How can I add color to an anchor element in Overleaf?

Tags: html, href, resume, overleaf

Googled and tried couple of solutions added href attribute but the links after \begin doesn't get colored, please help me in this situation
Here's the code

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Deedy - One Page Two Column Resume
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.2 (16/9/2014)
%
% Original author:
% Debarghya Das (http://debarghyadas.com)
%
% Original repository:
% https://github.com/deedydas/Deedy-Resume
%
% IMPORTANT: THIS TEMPLATE NEEDS TO BE COMPILED WITH XeLaTeX
%
% This template uses several fonts not included with Windows/Linux by
% default. If you get compilation errors saying a font is missing, find the line
% on which the font is used and either change it to a font included with your
% operating system or comment the line out to use the default font.
% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% 
% TODO:
% 1. Integrate biber/bibtex for article citation under publications.
% 2. Figure out a smoother way for the document to flow onto the next page.
% 3. Add styling information for a "Projects/Hacks" section.
% 4. Add location/address information
% 5. Merge OpenFont and MacFonts as a single sty with options.
% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% CHANGELOG:
% v1.1:
% 1. Fixed several compilation bugs with \renewcommand
% 2. Got Open-source fonts (Windows/Linux support)
% 3. Added Last Updated
% 4. Move Title styling into .sty
% 5. Commented .sty file.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Known Issues:
% 1. Overflows onto second page if any column's contents are more than the
% vertical limit
% 2. Hacky space on the first bullet point on the second column.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%  \definecolor{links}{HTML}{2A1B81}
% \hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=,urlcolor=links}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}


 \usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{hyperref} 


\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     LAST UPDATED DATE
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     TITLE NAME
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\namesection{Yuvraj}{A}{ \urlstyle{same}\href{https://yuvraj-agarkar.netlify.app/}{yuvraj-agarkar.com} \\
\href{mailto:yuvraj@gmail.com}{yuvraj@gmail.com} | +80 0000000 
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     COLUMN ONE
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     EDUCATION
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Education} 

\subsection{Savitribai Phule Pune University}
\descript{BTech IN Computer Engineering}
\location{2025 | college}
\sectionsep

\subsection{Computer Engineering}
\descript{Diploma in Computer Engineering}
\location{2019-2022 | Pune, Maharashtra}
Pimpri Chinchwad Polytechnic\\
\location{ Aggregate: 91.77\% }
\sectionsep


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     LINKS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Links} 
Twitter:// \href{https://twitter.com/agarkaryuvraj?lang=en}{\bf @AgarkarYuvraj} \\
Github:// \href{https://github.com/Yuvraj102}{\bf yuvraj102} \\
Leetcode://  \href{https://leetcode.com/}{\bf foobar} \\
LinkedIn://  \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/yuvraj-agarkar-770a861a4/?originalSubdomain=in}{\bf foobar} \\
GFG://  \href{https://auth.geeksforgeeks.org/user/yuvrajagarkar24}{\bf yuvrajagarkar24} \\
Website://  \href{https://yuvraj-agarkar.netlify.app/}{\bf Portfolio}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     COURSEWORK
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Activities}
\subsection{Hackathons}
Participated in Girl Script Hackathon \\
Created a job portal for women's In rural areas \\
Used EJS for templating, Extendable templates\\
Nodejs as a runtime Environment\\
Expressjs on top of Nodejs\\
Firebase, Cloud Firestore\\
\sectionsep

\subsection{Tech Twitter}
Consistently Interacting With the Tech Community on Twitter\\
Built >followers\\
Twitter tech spaces, threads etc\\
Writing Blogs on Medium\\
Tech Lead at E-cell Rscoe club\\


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     SKILLS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Skills}
\subsection{Programming}
% \location{Over 5000 lines:}
C/C++ \textbullet{}   HTML/CSS \textbullet{} Python \textbullet{} Javascript \\
Nestjs \textbullet{} Reactjs \textbullet{} Expressjs  \\
\textbullet{} Native iOS \textbullet{} Swift \textbullet{} DBMS \textbullet{} MongoDB \textbullet{} SQL \textbullet{} Various Other Libraries
\\ \location{Tools used:}
Vscode \textbullet{} Atom \textbullet{} Git and Github \textbullet{} Postman \textbullet{} npm \textbullet{} DBeaver


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     COLUMN TWO
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{minipage} 
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.66\textwidth} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     EXPERIENCE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Experience}
\runsubsection{Bell}
\descript{| Frontend Developer }
\location{August 2022 – Present | Remote}
\vspace{\topsep} % Hacky fix for awkward extra vertical space
\begin{tightemize}
\item Building scalable backend platform for bells, 
\item Nodejs Developer, Nestjs framework, Typescript and Javascript. 
\item Postgres Sql, Heroku and AWS, Node mailer, Google Auth, 
\end{tightemize}
\sectionsep

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     RESEARCH
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Projects}
\runsubsection{Student's Portal}
\descript{| Social Student's Community}
Created a social platform for students to share their doubts \textbf{\href{https://sd.netlify.app/}{Live here}} \textbf {Implemented roles management, Google Auth, Cloud storage, Deployment, Sockets, Nodejs, Expressjs, Reactjs}  \\ 
Student's and Teachers can interact, Upload Notes, Create Profile, Doubts, Upvote/Downvote posts
\sectionsep

\runsubsection{Daily Journal}
\descript{| Journaling Platform }
Created a journaling platform, \textbf {Implemented Auth, Follow and Unfollow other users, Image Upload and Retrive from Cloud (Cloudinary Storage), Nodejs, Expressjs, pug templating, Nodemailer for sending email updates, HTML/CSS, Onrender, MongoDB and Mongoose etc.}
Live platform \textbf{\href{https://daily-journal-co.com/}{here}, \href{https://github.com/Yuvraj102/daily_journal_public}{source code}}
\sectionsep

\runsubsection{Object Detection}
Created an iOS App for detecting object using machine learning via phone camera, \textbf {used REST api (wikipedia), Swift programming, Xcode editor, Machine learning model, MVC design pattern, Cocoa pods}
\textbf{\href{https://github.com/yuvraj/ObjectsDetectionApp/}{(Source Code)}} \\
\textbf{\emph{Other Projects}} \href{https://github.com/Yuvraj102/spotifyClone}{Spotify}, \href{https://github.com/Yuvraj102/Airbnb-clone}{Airbnb}, \href{https://github.com/Yuvraj102/Amazon-Ui}{Amazon}, 
\href{https://github.com/Yuvraj102/Niyati-Trail}{Niyati Trail (Group Project)}, 
\href{https://github.com/Yuvraj102/Slack-Clone}{Slack} \\
\textbf{\emph{\href{https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/abc}{Video Demonstration}}} 
\sectionsep

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     AWARDS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Articles}
\textbf{[1].} \href{https://yuvraj-agarkar.medium.com/your-very-first-react-app-building-a-react-app-from-scratch-939c542a828c}{Your Very First React App} \\[1\baselineskip]
\textbf{[2].} \href{https://yuvraj-agarkar.medium.com/your-very-first-sass-project-what-is-sass-how-to-use-it-d947e61d1713} {Your Very First SASS project} \\[1\baselineskip]
\textbf{[3].} \href{https://yuvraj-agarkar.medium.com/filemanager-in-swift-ios-storing-in-plist-file-4fb1ec94855}{Filemanager in Swift and How to Use it ?} \\ [1\baselineskip]
\textbf{[4].} \href{https://yuvraj-agarkar.medium.com/database-connectivity-with-java-using-mysql-5bf9c1802786}{Databse connectivity with java} \\ [1\baselineskip]
\textbf{[5].} \href{https://yuvraj-agarkar.medium.com/threading-multithreading-made-easy-using-java-dfa2c298aa45}{Threading, Multithreading made easy (using java)}
\sectionsep


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     PUBLICATIONS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



\end{minipage} 
\end{document}  \documentclass[]{article}
```

here's the entire code, i have tried couple of solutions but it just doesnt work for href link after \begin{document} tag
All the links before that work but just the links after that tag shows no effect on their color property

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] which actually reproduces your problem and add a link to the exact same version of the class you are using.

Comment: I have made the changes as required, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This template tries very, very hard to switch off all possibilities of coloured links:

- it loads `hyperref` with the `hidelinks` option. You can undo this with the `colorlinks` option
- it loads it special font with an explicit colour (https://github.com/deedy/Deedy-Resume/blob/master/OpenFonts/deedy-resume-openfont.cls#L28). You can overwrite this forced colour by loading the font again without colour

---

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,urlcolor=green}

\setmainfont[Path = fonts/lato/,BoldItalicFont=Lato-RegIta,BoldFont=Lato-Reg,ItalicFont=Lato-LigIta]{Lato-Lig}


\begin{document}

test

\href{example.com}{link text}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesnt change to any other color than red?, i tried `\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=BlueViolet}`  doesnt work, not even blue